# Markdown package -- tight lists

Tags: lists, markdown

I am using the markdown package within Latex (https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)

My document contains a lot of lists (my main motivation for using markdown) and I want some more control over how they are rendered.  Mainly, I want to add extra white space between the main text and lists (I am using tightLists package option)

I tried two solutions:

1. Make a command that wraps around the markdown environment and adds white space.  This does not render text at all (ie just whitespace)

> ```
> \newcommand\md[1]{
> \vspace{2mm}
> \begin{markdown}
> #1
> \end{markdown}
> \vspace{2mm}
> }
> \md{Hello world}  % renders no text, only white space
> ```

2.Redefine the markdown package commands that render lists.  This works, but produces extra space between items in nested list -- I just want whitespace at the outer-most block.

```
\newcommand\listspace{\vspace{2mm}}
\renewcommand\markdownRendererOlBeginTight{%
    \listspace%
    \markdownRendererOlBeginTightPrototype%
}%
\renewcommand\markdownRendererOlEndTight{%
    \markdownRendererOlEndTightPrototype%
    \listspace%
}%
\renewcommand\markdownRendererUlBeginTight{%
    \listspace%
    \markdownRendererUlBeginTightPrototype%
}%
\renewcommand\markdownRendererUlEndTight{%
    \markdownRendererUlEndTightPrototype%
    \listspace%
}%
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you edit your question to provide a small but fully compiling example that shows the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do what you are after. The trick is to change the definitions of the renderers as we nest the lists:

1. We start with the definitions named `outer`.
2. We switch to the definitions named `top-inner` after the beginning of a top-level list.
3. We switch to the definitions named `inner` after the beginning of a second-level list.

As we bubble up from the nested lists, we will automatically restore the previous definitions by parenthesizing the lists with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}

\newcommand\listspace{\vspace{2mm}}

% The default top-level definitions
\markdownSetupSnippet{outer}{
  renderers = {
    ulBeginTight = {%
      \listspace
      \markdownRendererUlBeginTightPrototype
      \begingroup
        \markdownSetup{snippet = top-inner}
    },
    olBeginTight = {
      \listspace
      \markdownRendererOlBeginTightPrototype
      \begingroup
        \markdownSetup{snippet = top-inner}
    },
  },
}

% Definitions after the beginning of the top-level list
\markdownSetupSnippet{top-inner}{
  renderers = {
    ulBeginTight = {%
      \markdownRendererUlBeginTightPrototype
      \begingroup
        \markdownSetup{snippet = inner}
    },
    olBeginTight = {%
      \markdownRendererOlBeginTightPrototype
      \begingroup
        \markdownSetup{snippet = inner}
    },
    ulEndTight = {%
      \endgroup
      \markdownRendererUlEndTightPrototype
      \listspace
    },
    olEndTight = {%
      \endgroup
      \markdownRendererOlEndTightPrototype
      \listspace
    },
  },
}

% Definitions after the beginning of the second-level list
\markdownSetupSnippet{inner}{
  renderers = {
    ulBeginTight = {%
      \markdownRendererUlBeginTightPrototype
      \begingroup
    },
    olBeginTight = {%
      \markdownRendererOlBeginTightPrototype
      \begingroup
    },
    ulEndTight = {%
      \endgroup
      \markdownRendererUlEndTightPrototype
    },
    olEndTight = {%
      \endgroup
      \markdownRendererOlEndTightPrototype
    },
  },
}

\markdownSetup{
  tightLists = true,
  hashEnumerators = true,
  snippet = outer,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
some text

- first item
- second item
    - nested first item
    - nested second item
        - doubly nested item
- third item


#. first item
#. second item
    #. nested first item
    #. nested second item
        #. doubly nested item
#. third item

some more text
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

[image: the output of saving the above code as a file named example.tex and executing lualatex example.tex]

The Markdown package refers to these named definitions as *snippets* and they are part of Markdown since version 2.10.0 (2021-08-06), see also [my TUGboat article that introduces snippets](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-2/tb131novotny-markdown.pdf).

Before version 2.10.0, you had to nest `\markdownSetup`s (or `\renewcommand`s), which can be a bit harder to read and write for humans. Additionally, you don't get to name the different sets of definitions, which is a lost opportunity at documenting your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine `\markdownRendererUlBeginTight` and `markdownRendererUlEndTight` to include some extra space. This is similar to your own approach but affects only the start and end of the lists.

MWE to show the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tightLists=true]{markdown}
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{markdown}
- list first item
- list second item
- list third item
\end{markdown}
some more text\\[5mm]

\def\markdownRendererUlBeginTight{\vspace{5mm}\begin{compactitem}}
\def\markdownRendererUlEndTight{\end{compactitem}\vspace{5mm}}
% and similar for ordered lists
some text
\begin{markdown}
- list first item
- list second item
- list third item
\end{markdown}
some more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in an actual document you would put the redefinitions in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tightLists=true]{markdown}
\def\markdownRendererUlBeginTight{\vspace{5mm}\begin{compactitem}}
\def\markdownRendererUlEndTight{\end{compactitem}\vspace{5mm}}
\begin{document}
[...]
```

Side by side view to show this doesn't add extra space between items compared to the regular `tightLists` option:

[image]

Comment: To cite @LogZ, this "produces extra space between items in nested list -- I just want whitespace at the outer-most block."

Comment: @Witiko actually it doesn't add extra space between the items, see edit.

Comment: Neither does @LogZ's code, but you haven't tried nesting them. When you do, you will see that the nested lists will have 5mm vertical spaces around them. I address this shortcoming in my answer.

Comment: @Witiko a I see, I didn't consider the nesting aspect indeed. Maybe you can add an actual usage example and a screenshot to your own answer, to highlight the nesting part more clearly?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea, I just did.